# Redirect Http Url to Https in Elastic beanstalk loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, https, elastic-load-balancer

I've my spring boot app running on tomcat EC2 instances behind the Loadbalancer, which has configured with Https and internelly using Http.

I want to redirect url requests to HTTP to HTTPS.

I found this [document](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/) from AWS Support

As it says I need to config the Apache backend with the following config

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http

RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

My Question is where to add these config?

There is another document says i need to add .ebextensions directory to the webapp directory and place configurations there. If that is the case, then what is the directory structure and config file format ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a folder `.ebextensions` in the root of your project (and make sure it is in the root of the bundle you're uploading to Elastic Beanstalk. Something like this:

```
~/workspace/my-app/
|-- .ebextensions
|   -- httpd
|      -- conf.d
|         -- myconf.conf
-- index.jsp
```

in `myconf.conf`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

There is a whole article on customizing the Java apps running in Elastic Beanstalk Tomcat: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html Have a look for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll test it.

Comment: It is not working. In the logs I found      
"Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"

Comment: I mark it as accepted as it is answering the main question about directory structure.  For full answer check the answer below.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805261/redirect-http-url-to-https-in-elastic-beanstalk-loadbalancer/44829374#44829374

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution create a config file in the following location

```
~/workspace/server/
|-- .ebextensions
|   -- httpd
|      -- conf.d
|         -- abc.conf
```

with the following content

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ELB-HealthChecker
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

   <Proxy *>
     Require all granted
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
   ProxyPreserveHost on

   ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log

</VirtualHost>
```

Load mod_rewrite is required in newer Tomcat installations.

Source:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html