# .ebextensions conf file not getting detected

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, redirect, https

I am running a single instance machine behind a load balancer and I am able to setup the secure port domain to work for https://www.example.com.

I am trying to redirect both http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com

I am running Tomcat 8 on the instance behind the load balancer

I was toying around with AWS extensions to make the redirect work and I used the following links for my reference to create a .ebextensions directory.

[Redirect Http Url to Https in Elastic beanstalk loadbalancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805261/redirect-http-url-to-https-in-elastic-beanstalk-loadbalancer/44829374#44829374)

I dont see the .ebextensions directory after deployment in the tomcat root folder

The content on elasticbeanstalk.conf doesnt include the rewrite rules and module reloads that I added to make the redirect work .It still seems to contain the default values the file had before deployment. Seems the .ebextensions didnt get executed at all

I have installed an AWS certificate manager on my load balancer.

I am able to manually access https://www.example.com

Cant figure out if I am missing something? Can someone in the community help me resolve the issues.

Comment: I am creating a .conf file. Should the extension be .conf or .config

Comment: How are you packaging your Tomcat application (i.e. using Maven and generating a .war file)?

Comment: Yes..using maven.Referred this link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423932/where-to-add-ebextensions-in-a-war

Comment: Looking forward for some help from the community.